# How to do for each in Struts 2

Tags: java, html, jsp, struts2

I am trying to build a slider for a web page in HTML.
Which gets values from an ArrayList(named testList) from a struts action. And I want 
to display 6 values from the list at a time in this pattern.for ex:

If the array is of size 26, {0,1,2,3,4,5} then {6,7,8,9,10,11} then {11,12,13,14,15} .. and so on upto {24,25} ,rest values even if null its ok.

Something like for each loops: 
`for(i=0;i<size;i+6){}`

But currently I get the values from the list in this pattern :

{0,1,2,3,4,5} then {1,2,3,4,5,6} then {2,3,4,5,6,7} ..

Which is because the index(#status.index)iterates in the following pattern {0,1,2,3...}
I want the index to increment by 6 everytime instead of 0 to 1 to 2 etc.

I added step="6" , but this is not working.

Here is a sample of my code below:

```
 <ul class="slider">
        <s:iterator step="6" status="status" value="testList" >
        <li> <!-- FIRST SLOT OF DATA --> 
            <div class="rightSubContainer">
                    <s:iterator value="testList[#status.index]" >
                        <table >
                            <tr>
                                <th>
                                    <p align="center"><b ><font color="#151B54"><s:property value="name" /></font></b></p>
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <!-- ...values  -->
                    </s:iterator>       
            </div>
            <div class="rightSubContainer">
                    <s:iterator value="testList[#status.index+1] " >
                        <table >
                            <tr>
                                <th>
                                    <p align="center"><b ><font color="#151B54"><s:property value="name" /></font></b></p>
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <!-- ...values  -->
                    </s:iterator>       
            </div>
            <div class="rightSubContainer">
                    <s:iterator value="testList[#status.index+2]" >
                        <table >
                            <tr>
                                <th>
                                    <p align="center"><b ><font color="#151B54"><s:property value="name" /></font></b></p>
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <!-- ...values  -->
                    </s:iterator>   
            </div>
            <!-- ... and so on.. upto 6 values -->
```

Comment: There is an edit button under your question.

Comment: What version of Struts are you using?

Comment: Edited please check the question,
I am using Struts 2

Comment: @AdityaHandady And major minor versions Of Struts2?

Comment: Struts 2.0 only, If thats what you meant to ask.

Comment: @AdityaHandady If you edit your question first look who is edited it already and what changes have been made. Choose the question mark to get help about how to do edits, and not override changes that was made to make your question readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why one table for each value ? Why 1337 iterators instead of a single one ? Why `<b>`, `<font>` etc instead of using CSS ?

By the way you simply need to use the `%` (module operator) to check if the current position is a multiple of six; if it is, you need to split the `<li>`;

Note that `IteratorStatus.count` is the same as `IteratorStatus.index + 1`, because it is `1-based`;

Ugly way:

```xml
<ul class="slider">
    <li>
        <s:iterator status="status" value="testList" >          
                <table >
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            <p align="center"><b ><font color="#151B54">
                                <s:property value="name" />
                            </font></b></p>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            <s:if test="%{#status.count % 6 == 0}" >
                </li>
                <li>
            </s:if>
        </s:iterator>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Better way:

```xml
<ul class="slider">
    <li>
        <s:iterator status="status" value="testList" >          
                <p>
                    <s:property value="name" />
                </p>
            <s:if test="%{#status.count % 6 == 0}" >
                </li>
                <li>
            </s:if>
        </s:iterator>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and in CSS (or inside a `<style></style>` block in the `<head>` element)

```
ul.slider > li > p {
    text-align: center;
    color: #151B54;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #ddd;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this was very helpful. Also sorry for mylate reply. I actually imlpemented :

<s:if test="%{#status.index % 6 == 0}" > 

instead of 

<s:if test="%{#status.count % 6 == 0}" > 

and it worked for me.
This could still be the ugly way, is it?

Comment: No, the ugly was referred to all the HTML markup (a table for each row, where it can be achieved with a single div or p element and CSS); You are right, my mistake: .count split on sixth element, while .index split on seventh element; put .index before the <p>, or .count AFTER the <p>. I'll edit now